# How to move greated texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-coordinates

How to move created gradient without customizing Texture Gradients from which created gradient created?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find the texture coordinate node within your tree (it may be helpful to expand out the node groups) and attach a *Mapping* node.  This allows you to translate and rotate your coordinate space.

[image]

Attach the same mapping node to both locations of textures from which you created your Final Texture.

[image]

Comment: I merged my answer into yours